# Groovy: delegate property in enum

Tags: groovy

I have the following code in Groovy 1.8.5 and to me it looks valid. Why does this give an error?

```
public enum Test
{
    ONE("meep"), TWO("jeep"), THREE("sheep");

    Test(String n)
    {
        this.n = n;
    }

    @Delegate String n;
}

println Test.ONE[1]
println Test.TWO[0]
```

**Edit 1:**
I have a number of enumerated objects, so I want to put them in an enum. Each value of the enum represents an instance of those objects so why not store them there? Now, groovy enables me to do, say `Test.One.digits` instead of `Test.One.n.digits`which is handier.

When i try to run it in eclipse i get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` which i interpret as the class not being compiled properly. I don't have the compiler message at the time though... I'm working on it.

**Edit 2:**

I got the script to work here though... http://gppconsole.appspot.com/script/34001
So I guess case closed and the problem is not the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What error do you get?

```
public enum Test
{
    ONE(1), TWO(2), THREE(3);

    Test(Integer n)
    {
        this.n = n;
    }

    @Delegate Integer n;
}

println Test.ONE.n
```

works in Groovy 1.8.6...  Though I'm not sure that adding a `@Delegate` to an enum is a good thing to do (I need to think about it more)...

What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The funny thing is that Eclipse doesn't even show an error so I haven't figured out what the actual error message is. The red icon is showing on the file icon, but when I try to run it it says it gives "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" which I interpret as my class not being build properly. I'll try with a newer version of Groovy